# Why my code selects the next cell? - UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm trying to create a way to select a cell so that I can edit it. With the current code, the cell that is going up is always the next cell. And my last cell in my `tableView` can not be selected.

```swift
@objc func handleLongPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location( in : self.view)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            let cell_selected = classements[indexPath.row]
            nomAjouterOutlet.text = cell_selected.nom
            pointAjouterOutlet.text = "\(cell_selected.point)"
            classeAjouterOutlet.text = cell_selected.classe!
            // Context CoreData
            context.delete(cell_selected)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!AppDelegate).saveContext()
            do {
                classements =
                try context.fetch(Tournoi.fetchRequest())
            } catch {
                print("Fetching Failed")
            }
            classementTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ClassementViewController.handleLongPress(_: )))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. Here is the code that works.

Swift 4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLongPressGesture()
}

func setupLongPressGesture() {
    let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.tblMessage.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tblMessage)
        if let indexPath = tblMessage.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {

        }
    }
}
```

From shareedit
answered Jan 18 at 11:05

PinkeshGjr
1,28121225

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP's response does not have enough explanation I wanted to add this answer as a complementary answer for the OP's answer. The mistake was actually in the following piece of code:

```swift
let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location( in : self.view)
```

Since the location is obtained from within the main `view`, the touch point returned is relative to `view`. However there is a difference between he **y points** of `view` and `tblMessage` which causing a shift to the below of the selected cell. This may be due to a navigation bar within the `view` that causing this shift in `y point`. If the height of the navigation ba is known we could get the correct touch point by applying the difference to the `touchPoint`'s `y` property such as `touchpoint.y -= navBarHeight`.
So the appropriate way of getting the touch point would be using the
`tableView` as an offset so that the `location(in:)` function can calculate the touch point correctly. Eventually, when we replace the `location(in:)`'s parameter from `view` to `tblMessage` which is tableView itself, we should get the correct point.

```swift
let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tblMessage)
```